# how to implement Fling on group

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to fling some images after some animations on them are over, and the animations run inside a window:
[image]

The red one which is above the other one, what I tried is:

```
if (xDn - xUp > 0) {
    Timeline.createSequence()
    .beginParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(GBMImage, SpriteAccessor.X, 0.2f)
    .target(170f))
    end().start(tweenManager);

}
```

where xDn and XUp are ontouchDown and ontouchUp x values. To move the image left and right.
Now the problem is on left, fling image goes over the back window, which I want to go beneath the red window. Secondly the above code is working for single image, I'm not able to understand how to apply it to group,