# Substitute for View Switcher/Flipper of android in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, tween

to display some animation in sequence of swipes  ,I calculated the touch up and down of image ,then using `tween` ,swapped the animation like this:

```
if (xDnSc10 - xUpSc10 < 0) {
    // move11Right();
    // runAnimation10();
}
if (xDnSc10 - xUpSc10 > 0) {
    // move10Left();
    runAnimation11();
}
```

,but in case of more then one image, swipe/fling is creating problem. So is it possible to use `viewFlipper` sort of thing on android ,in libgdx

Comment: ViewFlipper applies only to the Views. Unless your game uses Views, I don't see how you can use a ViewFlipper in a game. Can you elaborate? Maybe you need a ViewFlipper outside the game, to show the Menu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604795/how-to-implement-fling-on-group

Comment: I was looking for view flipper substitute for libgdx