# accessing Viewpager child elements for clicking and diplaying another view pager elements in a small window

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

I called the fragements as

```
           List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(context, Fragment1.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(context, Fragment2.class.getName()));
            mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);`
```

,but now in fragment class ,when trying to access the child button as

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {}
```

,but the button is not generating click event,not able to understand the problem.
Secondly, how can I open a small window with viewpager and fragments ,above the present window,so user touches the back window front one goes off,and when front window is visible,onclick of one of fragment button ,user can swipe its elements,as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604795/how-to-implement-fling-on-group) new in use of  viewpager,kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not completely understand the meaning of `inflater.inflate`, it was the same problem in your previous question.

When calling `inflater.inflate` it creat **new** View object from the xml you give it.

In this code:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {}
```

You created new view object, than you found it's button and add a touch listener event to it. Unless you are going to add this view to the fragment, the event will never fire.

I think what you meant to do is finding your view using `findViewById()` inside your fragment class.

Comment: thanx,I was actually facing prob in second part of question, i.e generating a dialog/small window with a viewpager and several other fragments with animations etc