# not able to access child elemnt of view pager fragment for onclick

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

using viewpager in my fragment class I tried to generate some animations on click of a fragment imageButton

and my  fragment class is

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
ImageButton btn;
Context cxt;

RelativeLayout fragment1;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

            btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.bJ);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ////some animations             
        }
    });


            return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
            container, false);
}
```

}
but my onclick event is not being generated ,using viewpager for first time ,pl guide,thanx

Comment: please format your code before pasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
            container, false);
```

to

```
return v;
```

Comment: can you pl help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754854/accessing-viewpager-child-elements-for-clicking-and-diplaying-another-view-pager

Answer (score 2):

You does not return view what you have handled your click's,
 try this,

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

            btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.bJ);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ////some animations             
        }
    });


            return v;
}
```