# viewpager not displaying child viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

in my class I'm calling another class to diplay fragment in dialog

```
   public class FragmentT extends Fragment implements AnimationListener {
    ImageButton btn;
    Context cxt;

    RelativeLayout fragmentT;


        View vPOp;
        Animation animation;
         ViewPager pager;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (container == null) {

            return null;
        }
        cxt=getActivity();
        this.activity=getActivity();
        vPOp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop, container, false);
        pager = (ViewPager) vPOp.findViewById(R.id.up);

        btn = (ImageButton) vPop.findViewById(R.id.button);



        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                new DialogFragmentWindow().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");

            }
        });



        return vPop;
    }






    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

where DialogFragmentWindow is

```
public class DialogFragmentWindow extends DialogFragment {
    PageAdapter pPageAdapter;
    Context context;
    ViewPager vp;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop, container);
        context = getActivity();
    //  this.activity=getActivity();
         vp = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pVF);

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
            FragmentAdapter pA = new FragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),fragments);

            vp.setAdapter(pA);

            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        return view;
    }


    private List getFragments() {
        List<Fragment> fragmentPop = new Vector<Fragment>();
        //fragmentPop.add(FragSc1.newInstance());
        fragmentPop.add(Fragment.instantiate(context,
                FragSc1.class.getName()));
        fragmentPop.add(Fragment.instantiate(context,
                FragSc2.class.getName()));

        return fragmentPop;
    }



}
```

so the problem is,neither do  DialogFragmentWindow is accepting the argument getChildFragmentManager(),nor do the FragmentT class is taking,

```
new DialogFragmentWindow().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
```

the viewpager i'm calling is  in another layout so want to use getChildFragmentManager(),not able understand thwe prob,using chid fragment/viewpager for the first time.

Comment: what I m trying to do is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544829/viewpager-with-fragments-inside-popupwindow-or-dialogfragment-error-no-view

Answer (score 2):

Just try to do as like this. It may help you.

```
new DialogFragmentWindow().show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "dialog");
```

Comment: it is not even taking that arg

Comment: what you really want to do?

Comment: SECOND PART OF  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754854/accessing-viewpager-child-elements-for-clicking-and-diplaying-another-view-pager